# I want to generate sql query that much similar like table of content

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdlc

Our senario is that i want to developed an sql query like this

```
name address ward  mobile pageno
 A      00    1     9890    1
 B      01    1     9890    1
 C      01    1     9890    1
 A1     10    1     9890    2
 B1     101   1     9890    2
 B      01    1     9890    2
 A@     00    1     9890    3
 B#     01    1     9890    3
 C^     01    1     9890    3
 A11    10    1     9890    4
 B11    101   1     9890    4
 B11    01    1      9890   4
```

this our present situation and expected this check below

expected output:

[image: output expected]

I want this result at a bunch of 3 data with same page number then again three data with same page number and if "Ward" number change page number will be incremented by 1 for next 3 record and procedure gone same for next ward number change

Comment: Please properly format your question. It is hard to understand your table.

Comment: Please edit to show your input data and expected output, your description is hard to understand.

Comment: please check the image attached

Comment: Input and output is 2, and your image only has 1. Is it input data or your expected output? If it's input then what is your expected output, and vice versa?

Comment: assume its an table structure and now i want to increment next 3 record when ward number change and so on

Comment: please edit your question and show us the exptected outcome

Comment: So you want to number your records, giving the same number to a group of three. Do you want any particular order applied or doesn't it matter? (I.e. could I also give, say, C/B1/B# pageno 1, A/B/A11 pageno 2, etc.?)

Comment: yes  from start group of three assign number 1 and next3 assign number 2 if any war number change then again after ward change then next 3 record assign the current page number+1 to next 3 record

Answer (score 0):

You want to number your records in packs of three, but also increment the number on a ward change, so some packs may consist of 1 or 2 records only instead. This is difficult.

To get numbers 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3,  etc. you can use `row_number` and integer division. But for the ward change you must know up to which number the previous words counted. Here you'll have to use aggregation and integer division again. As the aggregation refers to the ward numbers previous to a current ward number, we need a correlated query, which we apply with `cross apply`:

```
select
  name,
  address,
  ward,
  mobile,
  (row_number() over(partition by ward order by name) - 1) / 3 + 1 +
    previous_wards_aggregated.pagenumbercount as pagenno
from mytable
cross apply
(
  select coalesce(sum(ward_pagenumbercount), 0) as pagenumbercount
  from
  (
    select ward, (count(*) - 1) / 3 + 1 as ward_pagenumbercount
    from mytable before
    where before.ward < mytable.ward
    group by ward
  ) previous_wards
) previous_wards_aggregated
order by ward, name;
```

I have used `name` as the sort criteria, as you haven't specified any. Change this, in case you want another order.

**REXTESTER:** http://rextester.com/QAASX4340

Comment: this query gives wrong data because when ward change the start such a big number  why and query count start from 2 not by one 1 why ?

Comment: I don't see what you mean. If you click the rextester link, you see that the first three rows get #1, the next three #2, the next one #3 (because this is the last row for that ward), then two #4 (because there are only two for that ward), etc. Looks fine to me. How is this different from what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try this with other sample data and post that sample data for it not working.

```
DECLARE @Pageindex INT = 1 -- this is parameter that need to be pass in proc
DECLARE @Pagesize INT = 3 -- this is not parameter.it is inside proc


DECLARE @t TABLE (
    NAME VARCHAR(50),addres VARCHAR(50)
    ,ward VARCHAR(50),mobile VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @t
VALUES

 ('A  ','00 ',1,'9890') ,('B  ','01 ',1,'9890')
 ,('C  ','01 ',1,'9890'),('A1 ','10 ',1,'9890') 
 ,('B1 ','101',1,'9890')  ,('B  ','01 ',1,'9890') 
 ,('A@ ','00 ',1,'9890')  ,('B# ','01 ',1,'9890') 
,('C^ ','01 ',1,'9890')  ,('A11','10 ',1,'9890')  
 ,('B11','101',1,'9890')  ,('B11','01 ',2,'9890')
 ,('A22','10',2,'9890'),('B21','101 ',2,'9890')
 ,('B12','01 ',2,'9890') ,('ak1','10',4,'9890')
 ,('Bmm','01 ',4,'9890'),('B13','01 ',4,'9890')

;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *
        --,DENSE_RANK()over(order by ward) rownum
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY ward
            ) rownum2
    FROM @t
    )
    ,CTE1
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,CASE 
            WHEN (rownum2 % @Pagesize) = 0
                THEN (rownum2 / cast(@Pagesize AS FLOAT))
            ELSE CEILING((rownum2 / cast(@Pagesize AS FLOAT)))
            END PageIndex
    FROM cte c
    )
SELECT NAME
    ,addres
    ,ward
    ,mobile
    ,PageIndex
FROM cte1
```